# My spriteSheet animation crashes my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, crash, cocos2d-iphone

so I'm creating a sprite every second but now I would like to replace this sprite by a spriteSheetAnimation. but when I run this code my app crashes :

```
- (void)spawnCat {
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet2 = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"AnimBulle.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet2];

    // Load up the frames of our animation
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AnimBulle%d.png", i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames
                                                       delay:0.1f];
    [target runAction:_walkAction];
    target.tag = 1;
    [_targets addObject:target];

    [self addBoxBodyForSprite:target];
    [spriteSheet2 addChild:target z:0 tag:1];
    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration 
                                        position:ccp(240, 160)];
    id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
                                             selector:@selector(spriteDone:)];
[target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];
}
```

Comment: what kind of crash? what is the output on the console?

Comment: I don't know because I always have an error not enough frames in stack so I can't see what is in the console :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
From the kind of error you get (not enough stack traces), you have an inifinite recursion (i.e., a method that ends up calling itself, either directly or indirectly). The code in `spawnCat` does not seem to entail such an infinite recursion, so the problem must be somewhere else.

How do you call `spawnCat`? could you put some NSLog traces in the methods that are executed to create the animation, so that you see if someone keeps calling itself?

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Are you sure this is what you meant?

```
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
[target runAction:_walkAction];
```

I can't see `_walkAction` initialization, but I would expect you do that *after* creating the animation by doing something like:

```
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
_walkAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
[target runAction:_walkAction];
```

Comment: yes that's what I've done , I forgot to put it in my question, but why my app crashes

Comment: the error :" not enough frames in stack" come to all my project, it is not specific to this one .But this isn't the main error because I can still build and run, my only error come from this part of code particularily I don't know why

Comment: I can suggest two approaches: 1) add NSLog traces in your code to see what is executed and what not (so you narrow down the potential causes); 2) try to comment out pieces of your code (one at a time) and see if it gets better (this way, you find the culprit). If the debugger does not work, those are the only options I see. Have also a look at the device log in Xcode organizer to see if you find a crash report...

Comment: I actually forgot to put the CCAnimation into a CCAnimate - you're answer clarified that for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can see in the code is the possibility that your spriteFrame is not found. When you try to add nil to an array, you can get nasty outcomes. I would amend the loop as follows (logging helps).

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) { 
    NSString *sfn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AnimBulle%d.png", i];
    CCSpriteFrame *sf = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:sfn];
    if(sf) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:sf];
    } else {
        CCLOGERROR(@"%@<spawnCat> : *** Sprite frame named [%@] not found in cache, bailing out.",self.class,sfn);
        return; // ok here, nothing is retained before this may be executed
    }
}
```

Also, can you ensure that you actually loaded the spriteFrameCache with the .plist and texture before invoking this AND that you dont removeUnusedSpriteFrames from the cache anywhere else in the run loop.